# How to access Ultrasonic sensor using pyfirmata in python

Tags: python, arduino

**I use this code.but it is not working. can someone help me?I got this type of error
*raise IOError("{0} is set up as an INPUT and can therefore not be written to"
OSError: Digital pin 8 is set up as an INPUT and can therefore not be written to* **

```
import pyfirmata
import time
board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')


start=0
end=0

trigpin = board.get_pin('d:7:o')
echopin= board.get_pin('d:8:i')

trigpin.write(0)
time.sleep(5)

while True:
    trigpin.write(1)
    time.sleep(3)
    trigpin.write(0)

    while echopin.write(0):
        pass
        start = time.time()
    while echopin.write(1):
        pass
        end = time.time()

    print((end - start)/58.0*1000000)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm no Arduino expert but it seems to me that the error message has told you exactly what is wrong. `echopin= board.get_pin('d:8:i')` sets pin 8 up as an input pin. But in line 19 your code is writing to it. The error message suggests your code should be reading from it. And in future, please post the whole of the error message you get, including the full stack trace. Even if you think it's meaningless nonsense. It isn't nonsense to the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: BoarGules-Thankyou mate